# SQL INSERT, Force Truncate Field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have input data containing some "rogue" fields that are longer than the corresponding database field. This causes my import script, which uses SQL INSERT statements to fall over with a warning:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 2
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

How can I force truncation of these fields and enable my script to complete?

Comment: Have you tried converting to a varchar of a certain length? If it is greater than the specified length it would cut off the end.

Answer (score 14):

When you insert do something along the lines of :

```
INSERT INTO Table1('Column1') VALUES(LEFT(RTRIM(InputField), MaxLength))
```

You'll only store the Left N characters to the DB.

Comment: Thanks dude, this is good enough (even though it involves modifying all the relevant import statements).

Answer (score 13):

Use Ansi Warnings? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190368(v=sql.110).aspx

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    Data VARCHAR(3)
)

SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

INSERT INTO @TABLE 
VALUES('Hello World')

SELECT * FROM @TABLE

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

INSERT INTO @TABLE 
VALUES('Goodbye World')

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

Comment: In some situations, this type of 'band aid' solution can be useful. Tread carefully, however.

Comment: Agreed. This is dangerous to use regularly, *ONLY* as a very quick & dirty hack that should not go anywhere near a productive environment.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I want them to fail and then look at the data. I do not believe you should ever consider automated truncation of data. You could actaully need to make your field defintion larger. You won't know unless you visually inspect the rows that would fail.

Example: We store Speech titles. Suppose you had two titles:
How to Read a Book:
How to read a Book in the Bathtub without getting it wet

Now if your field had 10 characters both would get truncated to the same thing. Moreover what they got truncated to wouldn't even make sense. Both would say "How to Rea"  Now you don't have a difference bewteeen two very differnt titles and what you do have isn't correct anyway. Adjusting the field to store some higher amount of characters is clearly the correct thing to do. This example is silly, but garbage in, garbage out. If you truncate the names of people or other critical data, you will eventually have problems because you have garbage data. I've seen this happen with our speech titles, with last_names, with addresses, with phone numbers and lots of other data. If you have to truncate the data, more than likely you are storing useless data for that record anyway. Either the data needs correct cleanup (Such as removing the ()- from a phone number if you are designed only store the numbers) before importing into the production data or the field needs to be larger.

Comment: +1, but you could have also said at the end: "if you really need to, use LEFT()"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an easier way than tracking them down and using `LEFT()`.  I'd love to know if there is, though.

Obviously, using the metadata like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` you can determine this automatically and script it to do a `LEFT()` to the appropriate length.